# Go back in browser does not filter tags

Tags: feature-request, bug

After I select a tag and then click *go back* in my browser I am returned to the tags page with my previously selected tag still present in the input field but the tags are not filtered.  If I hit spacebar or anything else the filter script is triggered and tags are re-filtered as they should be.

Not sure if this is a bug or related to browser autofill but it would be nice if the tags were filtered based on the input field without needing to manually trigger the filter.

Comment: There's an awful lot of AJAXy things on SO that exhibit bad behavior in the face of back/forward navigation. I can't find the master dupe right now, though.